# ArcMap only plots some points of shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, chart, arcgis-10.7

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

I have a point shapefile with nine weather stations in Patagonia. It's available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT?usp=sharing). I want to plot all four variables as a bar chart for each station, so that you can see the increase or decrease of all parameters at one glance - a little bit like this:

[image]

The problem is that ArcMap only plots some of the stations, not all of them. If I just use the 'Features' symbology, it's no problem. If I plot the `AWS_ID`, it's no problem. But if I use any of the the 'Chart' symbologies for the four parameters, it just prints some of the points.

As Barry pointed out, some values are NAs (-9999), which I will have to deal with later. For the moment, I would be glad if they would just show together with the other values.

If you can reproduce this problem, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do realize that some of your values are -9999.0 which almost certainly means missing data?

Comment: Yes, some of my data is missing data, I have edited the question accordingly. I will have to deal with this later, but for the moment it should appear nevertheless, shouldn't it? Also, the other 'normal' values do not appear, either.

Comment: Try plotting only the two fields that don't have the -9999 data anywhere. Although your shapefile appears to be using -9999 as NODATA, it's not actually specified as such, which may be confusing arcgis

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made a selection of the four points without the NAs, but ArcMap still plots only two of them...

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but some of your points have AWS_ID `prec, temp` and others are just `prec`

Comment: Yeah, at some stations, we don't have temperature data, hence the -9999. But that should not influence the plotting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137310/discussion-between-florian-mlehliv-and-barrycarter).

Comment: Sorry, I'm tapped out of ideas :)